# php - mysql: storing string larger than field size

Tags: php, mysql

An attempt to **store** a **string larger than the field** (column) size will result in

- the **query failing**

or

- the string will be silently **truncated** to the max allowed length?

---

In other words:

should I take care of truncate strings too long before storing them or can I just store them and let the underlying system truncate them for me ?

---

**Side note**

I'm talking about data that I don't care if it gets truncated, of course.

Comment: it depends on your requirement , Imagine what happens if the password hash is truncated ?

Comment: @sumit: see my last edit. of course is kind of data I don't care if gets truncated. Surely not password hashes.

Comment: You should validate the data(In this case string length) in your business logic before insert command, if you don't do that then you may lose data & which is not god from product point of view

Comment: This would be easy to test...

Comment: Why on the earth this question has been flagged as "opinion based"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the current [`SQL_MODE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).

When mode is not strict, your query will produce only a warning, which is normally not visible to you unless requested explicitly. So in effect the string will be silently truncated to the max allowed length.

While in a strict mode, this query will result in a full-featured error and your query will fail

Answer (score -1):

If there is no PHP level validation the string will simply be truncated